# How is a node application run when it is being deployed?

Tags: node.js

When you are writing a node application on your computer, you can run it from your computer by typing in node . However, how does that happen when the application is being deployed.

Comment: Deployed where/how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you are writing a node application on your computer, you can run it from your computer by typing in node . However, how does that happen when the application is being deployed.

Basically the same way: there's not much of a difference between your computer and a computer in a data center. Either way, you start the process and it runs. It binds to a port that must be open, and then some firewall must be configured to allow incoming connections from the Internet to reach that port.

How you start the process in your "deployed" application varies greatly and is up to your needs and taste. You can:

1) [Provision a server somewhere, install node on there, put your code there, and then run your application](https://medium.com/swlh/quick-nodejs-deploy-guide-dbe836811c3e). You run it in the same way as your local computer. Log in to the computer and execute node. Or you can set it up to run with a [process manager.](https://superuser.com/questions/683325/how-to-monitor-a-service-and-restart-if-stopped-in-linux/687188#687188)

2) Use a PaaS like [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs).

3) Use a serverless environment like [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/).

You have many options and I'd explore them all!